# How to use React's useCallback hook to access multiple refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I pass useCallback as a node element ref, I can access it in a body function like this

```
   const ref = useCallback(node => console.log(node), [])
```

But how can I do the same with multiple nodes? For example, I have a canvas that is wrapped with a div element, and I need to access both of them to calculate the dimensions of the canvas.

Comment: What is the trigger for the height calculation? Is it just when the canvas is first added to the dom, after an event, etc? You can add a ref to each element and then use the refs in your `useCallback` or `useLayoutEffect`. Something similar to: `const divRef = useRef(); const canvasRef = useRef(); return <div ref={divRef}><canvas ref={canvasRef} /></div>;` Then you should be able to make use of `canvasRef.current` and `divRef.current` to get the DOM elements related to each.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JacobSmit! Yes, I guess I don't need useCallback. The useRef hook did the trick